# How can I expose kong admin api using kong k8 ingress?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kong-ingress

I deployed kong ingress controller for our kubernetes, and we are using it for routing our micro services.

Now I want to expose my admin API to use other features and get monitoring stats. Please someone could help me on this.

None of the documention helps me with this.

Comment: Hello, could you please tell if you are referring to the `CONTROLLER_KONG_ADMIN_URL` that is available on port `8444`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that we are focusing on:

> #### Admin API
>
> This is the port where Kong exposes its management API. Hence in production this port should be firewalled to protect it from unauthorized access.
>
> - `8001` provides Kong’s **Admin API** that you can use to operate Kong with HTTP. See [admin_listen](https://docs.konghq.com/2.3.x/configuration/#admin_listen).
> - `8444` provides the same Kong **Admin API** but using HTTPS. See [admin_listen](https://docs.konghq.com/2.3.x/configuration/#admin_listen) and the ssl suffix.
>
> -- *[Docs.konghq.com: 2.3.X: Configuration: Admin listen](https://docs.konghq.com/2.3.x/configuration/#admin_listen)*

From Kubernetes/GKE perspective you can access this ports with either:

- `$ kubectl port-forward deployment/ingress-kong -n kong 8444:8444`:

  - this option would allow you to query `https://localhost:8444` from your host
- `Service`:

  - Modify the `Service` of Kong Ingress
  - Modify the `Deployment` of Kong Ingress

> A side note!
>
> You could also expose it with `Ingress` resource but you would need to create a `Service` that is pointing to the `Admin API`, modify the `Deployment` and apply the `Ingress` resource that would point to this `Service`

---

Focusing on exposing this API with `Service`:

- Edit the `Service`: `kong-proxy` and add:

```yaml
  - name: api
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8444 
    targetPort: 8444
```

- Edit the `Deployment`: `kong-ingress`

```yaml
        - name: KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN
          value: 0.0.0.0:8444 ssl # <-- from 127.0.0.1
```

> **IMPORTANT!**
>
> Above edits will expose your API to the external sources (assuming no connection with the last question of yours with internal lb of GKE). Please refer to the documentation of Kong for support on that matter:
>
> - *[Docs.konghq.com: Gateway OSS: 2.3.X: Secure admin api](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.3.x/secure-admin-api/)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes:io: Docs: Tasks: Access application cluster: Port forward access application cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*

Comment: Thank you so much    

Comment: Thank you. Kong really should do a better job writing documents. This took so much time from me.

Comment: I cannot still send a request to the kong ingress controller's admin api. Neither through 127.0.0.1:8444 nor on the kong-proxy endpoint ip address:8444. I get connection refused error. What could be wrong?

Comment: So you are saying that even when you are trying to connect to it from localhost (directly from a Pod) it doesn't work? I'd check the configuration of Kong, the ports that is listens on.